# Is there any way to integrate invoice digitalization on odoo communtity edition

Tags: python, odoo

Is there any way to integrate invoice digitalization on odoo community edition

1. Vendor Bills from mail need to be OCR by the automation process

how to do this?

Comment: From email to odoo invoice is no problem at all by using aliases. Having a good OCR tool and using it in Odoo will be the challenge here.

Comment: Could you suggest any OCR tools?

Comment: No, because i have no experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

As the OCR of Odoo is an IAP service, the service itself is available for everyone, even without a valid Odoo enterprise license. This is indeed a REST API.

What is available in Odoo Enterprise is the integration of the OCR service in accounting app.

You still can use the OCR in community, but there is no given integration of it. You can find the documentation of the REST API here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/api/extract_api.html